# Comparing arrays in a text file - Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Animal1 {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Animal> animalFile = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("animal.txt"));
            String fileRead = br.readLine();            
            while (fileRead != null) {                
                String[] tokenSize = fileRead.split(":");
                String animalName = tokenSize[0];
                int maxLength = Integer.parseInt(tokenSize[1]);
                Animal animalObj = new Animal(animalName, maxLength);
                animalFile.add(animalObj);
                fileRead = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close(); 
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }
        System.out.println("The three largest animals are: ");
    }    
}
```

This is my code so far, it extracts the data from my animal file and outputs the Arrays I have created for each object in the file. How do I compare an Array in Java so I can print out the three largest animals, ordered by the largest first? I want to print the Animal name on a newline along with the max length.

Comment: by what do you determine the largest animal?

Comment: I've updated the code

Comment: Consider using the new I/O library called **NIO**, revolving around `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`. You can read line by line with `Files#lines` for example.

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the 3 largest animals you can do like this :

- `sort` the list by maxLength in reverse order to get largest first
- then `keep` the 3 first ones
- `print` them

```
animalFile.stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Animal::getMaxLength).reversed())
          .limit(3)
          .forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.animalName + ", length " + a.maxLength));
```

`getMaxLength()` is the getter method

---

First method won't keep the list sorted, this one yes :

```
Collections.sort(animalFile,Comparator.comparingInt(Animal::getMaxLength).reversed()); 
animalFile.stream().limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);  //Will use toString() you write
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the comparator?

Comment: @Mudz "the" comparator ? which one ?

Comment: Using something like this: `Collections.sort(list, new Dog());` Using Collections to sort out the Array then comparing them

Comment: @Mudz I've add, I let you find which is best and accept it :)

Comment: I've created a getter method already called getMaximumLength, should I use this rather than getMaxLength?

Comment: If the file is big you may consider doing **partial sort** instead of sorting **everything** just to get the 3 largest elements.

Comment: To find the three smallest animals, I just get rid of reversed from this code: `Collections.sort(animalFile,Comparator.comparingInt(Animal::getMaxLength).reversed());`

Comment: @Mudz to find the 3 smallest, juts remove `.reversed()`

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
animalFile.stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Animal::getMaxLength).reversed())
          .limit(3)
          .forEach(e -> { /* do logic */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Collections.sort(animalFile, Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingInt(a-> a.getMaximumLength())));

System.out.print("The 3 largest animals are: ");

animalFile.subList(0, 3).stream().forEach(n -> System.out.print(n.animalName + " "));
```

Comment: animalName comes out as an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - animalName has private access in task1.Animal`

Comment: @User786 The OP didn't show us the Animal class so some assumptions have to be made.  Perhaps the Animal class has a getter to use for animalName in which case n.animalName should be changed to n.getAnimalName().  There is no way to know for sure without seeing the animal class.